# Is there any way to add 'save cart for later' functionality to CartThrob?

Tags: cartthrob, shopping-cart

I would like to offer customers (who may have complex orders, with cart contents gathered over several weeks) the opportunity to save their cart for later, in order to complete their order on a subsequent visit, or visits. Is there any way to achieve this functionality with CartThrob?

I understand that the wishlist addon allows customers to assemble a list of products which can later be added to a cart, but the likely scenario is that customers have already started adding products to their order, and then realise that they will need to complete it later.

EDIT: it seems that CartThrob actually stores cart data in the DB and sets a cookie to associate user with cart. So perhaps it would just be necessary to modify Cartthrob_session.php to extend the length of the session cookie?

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I can think of some possible bodge ways of doing this like:
1. Use "Save Order" addon to first save the order, then later on use the checkout form with the order id.
2. Use "wish lists" addon, though I haven't yet found a suitable way to maintain all the product options.
3. Use Cartthrob's vault (not sure how this would work)...

I'd be interested in an ideal solution to this too.

Comment: Plus one on being interested to see if this is possible!

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable by enabling the `save_order` gateway in settings. The customer effectively performs a "checkout" like they normally would, but by using the save_order gateway, no payment is taken and the order is set to a status you choose in the settings area. You can then use something like the CT Order Loader to load the order back in to the cart at a later date.

I found that I needed to make a few tweaks to the Order Loader plugin, as it's not very secure in its current form: https://github.com/CartThrob/plugin-load-order (there are no checks that the order being loaded was created by the currently logged-in user). It also doesn't clear the cart before loading in a new order. Easy enough to add those things though.